# Interact with another window in application

Tags: winforms, appium, winappdriver

I have a simple application with button, which shows another form with ShowDialog() method. I would like to click close button from this opened form, but calling Session.FindElementByName("Close") will try to click close button from first form which fails (because another form is opened with ShowDialog()).

Any tips how I could switch to this new form?

SwitchTo doesn't seems to work.
I have two window handles in session after ShowDialog() call, but switching does not seems to work.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AppDriverTest_Close_Another_Window()
    {
        Session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("button1").Click();
        Session.FindElementByName("Close").Click();
    }

    // Form1 has button with following click method
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code once ? Did you tried alert or frame switch also ??

Comment: Tried also this, but it still didn't close the Form2:
            Session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("button1").Click();
            Session.SwitchTo().Window(Session.WindowHandles[1]);
            Session.FindElementByName("Close").Click();

Comment: [That's how `ShowDialog()` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/4934172). If you want the two forms to be accessible and want to be able to switch between them, use `.Show()` instead.

Comment: Is there any way to find active dialog and click its close button?

Comment: Did you try context switching?

Answer (score 1):

Got this working by adding whole "Path" to close button:

```
 Session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Form2").FindElementByName("Close").Click();
```